# Migrate carbon studio projects to 2.0.0

Tags: wso2

I have several cApp projects in Eclipse/Carbon Studio 1.0.14. Is there an "easy" way to migrate these to Developer Studio 2.0.0. If so, what's the best way to do it other than recreating all the artefacts and new cApp projects.
Also after uninstalling 1.0.14 and installing 2.0.0, my cApp projects are not recognized anymore as cApp projects.

Thanks and regards,

Danny

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to migrate other than recreating the projects with new Developer Studio 2.0.0.

We are planning on implementing a migration application which allows users to convert 1.x.x applications to 2.0.0 compatible versions. But we are unable to provide any solid timeline when this tool will be released.

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana